# Why isn't shift working in pyautogui.hotkey on certain scenarios?

Tags: pyautogui

I'm new to Python, so forgive me if I'm not being clear enough.

My problem is when the pyautogui.hotkey needs shift and an arrow, in other occasions.

For instance:

`pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'c')`

The code above works properly, however, on the next code, it "skips" the shift and acts like the parameters were `('ctrl', 'left')`, with no `'shift'`.

`pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'left')`

Why is this happening and what are some solutions I could apply?